# Solution of the harmonic oscilator using odeint does not match matlab solution

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, odeint

I am solving the harmonic oscilator using odeint and matlab. The equation I am trying to solve is `x'' = -x + 0.15*x'`. The odeint code can be found [here](https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/master/examples/harmonic_oscillator.cpp)

The exact solution is (per matlab):

```
S = (exp(-(3*z)/40)*(1591*cos((1591^(1/2)*z)/40) + 3*1591^(1/2)*sin((1591^(1/2)*z)/40)))/1591;
```

When I run odeint, using this integration method:

```
    {
    runge_kutta4< state_type > stepper;
    integrate_const( stepper , []( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t ) {
            dxdt[0] = x[1]; dxdt[1] = -x[0] - 0.15*x[1]; }
        , x , 0.0 , 10.0 , 0.01 );
    }
    //]


    //[ harm_iterator_const_step]
    std::for_each( make_const_step_time_iterator_begin( stepper , harmonic_oscillator, x , 0.0 , 10.0 , 0.01 ) ,
            make_const_step_time_iterator_end( stepper , harmonic_oscillator, x ) ,
            []( std::pair< const state_type & , const double & > x ) {
           std::cout << x.second << "\t" << x.first[0] << "\t" << x.first[1] << "\n";       } );


//]
```

I get the following picture for the 10 seconds: [odeint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjyEX.png)

But the graph in matlab is: [matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY3u4.jpg)

I could add the set of data, but as you can see from the picture, even the initial value in the odeint is wrong. It should be 1, but is (according the the code:

| 0 | -0.421912 | 0.246405 |

I have attached the first 0.1 seconds from both solutions to show the big discrepancy between the solutions:

Matlab:

| position |
| --- |
| 1.0000 |
| 0.9950 |
| 0.9803 |
| 0.9560 |
| 0.9226 |
| 0.8806 |
| 0.8304 |
| 0.7728 |
| 0.7084 |
| 0.6378 |
| 0.5621 |

Odeint:

| position |
| --- |
| -0.421912 |
| -0.419429 |
| -0.416908 |
| -0.414348 |
| -0.411751 |
| -0.409117 |
| -0.406446 |
| -0.403738 |
| -0.400994 |
| -0.398215 |
| -0.395399 |

I would expect that both applications render similar responses, but I cannot explain why they are so different. The analytical solution shows an exact match with the solver ode45 from matlab, which indicates to me that odeint is doing something weird.

Can someone please help understand the odeint internals so I can use it for my project? Currently, odeint would be an option, but I am sure if I am properly understanding the solution from odeint.

Answer (score 1):

I found my error. In the code that I copied from github, I did not realise that x was called by reference, so everytime I changed integrator, the value of x changed. This value was feeded into the next integator and rather than having fresh values, I gave the wrong values. I had a hiden integrator that I forgot to remove and this was causing the values to changed.

I think, me writing the question, helped me to understand the code I have copied. It was worth the time.